# Prepare for segue not passing data

Tags: swift, firebase, uicollectionview

I'm working on a Swift project using firebase and I have a UICollectionViewController that has all the categories, and I need to pass the category Id to the next view, but It passes an empty string

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let category = cnameArray[indexPath.row]
    let catId = category.caId
    func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
        if segue.identifier == "CatCity" {
        let cityView = segue.destination as? CityViewController
            cityView?.catId = catId!
    } }
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "CatCity", sender: self)

}
```

and in my CityViewController I have

```
    var catId = String()
```

when I put a break point at the last line of the prepare func it gets hit and the console gets the value correctly while sitting a breakpoint at CityViewController gives me an empty var.
and I checked the code and my segue name and everything looks fine!

Comment: I dont think your prepare func should be inside the didselectIteAt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct setup

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let category = cnameArray[indexPath.row]
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "CatCity", sender: category.caId)
}

func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
   if segue.identifier == "CatCity" {
      if let cityView = segue.destination as? CityViewController {
        cityView.catId = sender as! String
      } 
   }
}
```